# Php like system Ajax without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reload

I have a like system in my website. When I click on like, it like, when I reclick it unlike.
I want that, when I like, my page don't reload, so I tried Ajax, it works but I have to  reload the page to see changes.
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

post.php?p=34

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="posts">
        <?php
        while($question = $getQuestion->fetch()){
            ?>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="head">
                    <div class="title">
                        <?= $question['title']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date">
                        <?= ", ".$question['publication_date']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-card">
                    <?= "<div class='readMore'>" . $question['content'] . "</div>"; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <?php if($question['id_author'] == $_SESSION["id"]){ ?>
                        <div class="modifyBtn">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='editpost.php?id=<?= $question['id']; ?>'">Modify the post</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="deleteBtn">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='actions/posts/deleteQuestion.php?id=<?= $question['id']; ?>'"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="statsBtn">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='actions/posts/?id=<?= $question['id']; ?>'">Stats  <i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-vertical"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <section class="answers">
                    <div class="comments">
                        <form class="form-content" method="POST" id="postComment"> <!-- action="actions/posts/postAnswer.php" -->
                            <input name="answer" class="answer-btn" type="text" placeholder="Comment" autocomplete="off"><button type="submit" class="submit-btn" name="validate"><i class='fa-solid fa-paper-plane'></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                    
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="answers-container" id="answers-container">

                        <?php
                            while($answer = $getAnswers->fetch()){

                                    $getAnswerRating = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM answers_rating WHERE user_id = ? AND answer_id = ?");
                                    $getAnswerRating->execute(array($_SESSION["id"], $answer["id"]));

                                    $answer_id = $answer["id"];
                                ?>
                                <div class="answer">
                                    <div class="answer_header">
                                        <?= "<div class='author'>".$answer["username_author"]."</div>"; ?>
                                        <form method="POST" id="likeComment" class="formLikeComment">
                                            <div class="likes" id="likes">
                                                <button type="submit" class="addLikeSubmitBtn<?= $answer_id; ?>"> 
                                                    <?php 
                                                    if($getAnswerRating->rowCount() > 0){
                                                        ?>
                                                        <i class='fa-solid fa-heart' id='likeHeart'></i>
                                                        <?php 
                                                    }else{
                                                        ?>
                                                        <i class='fa-regular fa-heart' id='likeHearth'></i>
                                                        <?php
                                                    } 
                                                    ?>
                                                    <p><?= $answer["likes"]; ?></p>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="answer_body">
                                        <?= "<div class='answer_content'>".$answer["content"]."</div>"; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <script>
                                $(".formLikeComment").submit(function (e){
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $.get("actions/posts/answerLikes.php", { id : "<?= $answer_id; ?>" });
                            
                                })
                                </script>
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>

                    </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="assets/js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/maxstr.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        
        $(".form-content").submit(function (e){

            var answer_content = document.getElementById("answers-container");

            var answer = $(".answer-btn").val();

            var dataString = "answer=" + answer +"&post_id=" + <?= $_GET['p']; ?>

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "actions/posts/postAnswer.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });


            //$(".addLikeSubmitBtn").innerHTML = "<i class='fa-solid fa-heart'></i>";

        });
   </script>
```

actions/posts/answerLikes.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require("../config.php");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
}else{

    if(isset($_GET["id"]) AND !empty($_GET["id"])){

        $idAnswer = (int)$_GET["id"];
        $idUser = (int)$_SESSION["id"];

        $check = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id = ?");
        $check->execute(array($idAnswer));

        $Check = $check->fetch();

        if($check->rowCount() > 0){
            
            $ifAlreadyRated = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id FROM answers_rating WHERE user_id = ? AND answer_id = ?");
            $ifAlreadyRated->execute(array($_SESSION["id"], $_GET["id"]));

            if($ifAlreadyRated->rowCount() > 0){
               
                $deleteLike = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE answers SET likes = likes - ? WHERE id = ?");
                $deleteLike->execute(array("1", $_GET["id"]));
                $deleteRating = $bdd->prepare("DELETE FROM answers_rating WHERE user_id = ? AND answer_id = ?");
                $deleteRating->execute(array($_SESSION["id"], $_GET["id"]));

                header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."");

            }else{
                $insertLike = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE answers SET likes = likes + ? WHERE id = ?");
                $insertLike->execute(array("1", $_GET["id"]));
                $insertRating = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO answers_rating(username, user_id, answer_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
                $insertRating->execute(array($_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION["id"], $_GET["id"]));

                header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."");

            }

        }else{
            echo "error: " . $check->error;
        }

    }else{
        exit("Erreur fatale");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to get data from the PHP script you call. I guess it is in the name. You can use that to signal whether the item is liked or not. Use that to toggle the class of `#likeHeart` between `fa-regular` and `fa-solid`.